# Error: Response is not a function, when trying to find if the name exists

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

So I'm using mongodb to fetch some data from the database.

The issue is when I try to check for something in an array

Here is what the structure looks like:

Example array structure

```js
{ // ...
    likedPeople: [
        {
            name: "foo"
            image: "test",
        },
        {
            name: "bar",
            image: "baz",
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the array i get Back.

So when i try to find if it includes a certain value,
eg:

```js
const displayName = "foo";

console.log(
    likedPeople.map((likedPerson) => {
      return likedPerson.name === displayName; // Output: [true, false]
    })
  );
```

But then If i again try to do some other method on it like `map()` or `includes()`, It breaks the setup:

```js
const response = likedPerson.name === displayName; // Output: [true, false]
response.map((res) => console.log(res)); // Output: ERROR: response.map() is not a function
```

But the fact is that I am getting an array with the values, so what am I even doing wrong here?

I tried adding an optional chaining `response?.map()` but still it gave me the same error.

Also the `includes()` method also returns me the same `response.includes is not a function` error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In the code, it looks like `response` returns a boolean because you are comparing two values. And it doesn't return an array like this: `[true, false]`

Comment: @User456 in the browser, I am getting this output: `Array[true, false]` Although, when I try to check its type with `typeof response`, it returns the type `boolean` inside an array too: `Array["boolean", "boolean"]`

Comment: In the current code, it cannot be an array because you are just comparing it and not even using the `map` method on it. If it's a mistake, please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `some` method to check the name exists in `likedPeople` :

```js
const likedPeople = [
    {
        name: "foo",
        image: "test",
    },
    {
        name: "bar",
        image: "baz",
    }
];
    
const displayName = "foo";
const isExist = likedPeople.some(people => people.name === displayName);
console.log(isExist)
```